# Couldn't find platform family in Info.plist CFBundleSupportedPlatforms or Mach-O LC_VERSION_MIN for sqlite3

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, sqlite, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to build IOS app in ionic using `ionic build ios` The build is success. But when I use Xcode to deploy my App to apple store it is showing me above mentioned error.

I have gone through many github and stackoverflow issues but none of them worked for me. List of things I have tried:

1. Remove all .DSYM files
2. Add > CFBundleSupportedPlatforms as array and MacOSX as string to my info.plist
3. Removing all the Elements in my > Copy Bundle Resources
4. Clean project before building and the clicking archive option

Some of the links I found result:

1. https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/823
2. [Couldn't find platform family in Info.plist CFBundleSupportedPlatforms or Mach-O LC_VERSION_MIN for phantomjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34529583/couldnt-find-platform-family-in-info-plist-cfbundlesupportedplatforms-or-mach-o)

But none of these worked for me. I tested my app to my phone it is working properly but could not upload to apple store.

> There is no plugin installed in my Framework as sqlite but on
>   Validating it shows error with sqlite

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending so many hours, I solved it by deleting a file which in my www/lib folder with name sqlite, this was the part of some other library I was using and it was showing me this file even before I starting validating. Might help some one with same problem.

Answer (score 0):

For a React Native project your 3rd option worked for me, so I thought it should be emphasized.

Removing all the Elements in my `Build phases -> Copy Bundle Resources`