# couldn't find platform info.plist CFBundleSupportedPlatforms or Mach-O LC_VERSION_MIN for 2.7

Tags: ios, xcode, mach-o

I am currently trying to post an iOS app on the app store, but it is giving me this error:

> couldn't find platform info.plist CFBundleSupportedPlatforms or Mach-O LC_VERSION_MIN for 2.7

I've been going over the app store guide to make sure I didn't miss anything. Does anyone have any suggestions or see something I missed?

E: I found out that this has to do with static vs dynamically linked frameworks. Please read my comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Couldn't find platform family in Info.plist CFBundleSupportedPlatforms or Mach-O LC\_VERSION\_MIN for phantomjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34529583/couldnt-find-platform-family-in-info-plist-cfbundlesupportedplatforms-or-mach-o)

Comment: I'm finally getting somewhere with this. Taking a closer look at the logs I realized that this issue is pertaining to three of my frameworks - BZip2, Python, & OpenSSL. The number 2.7 was referring t the version number of Python being used which is dynamically linked. I've discovered that the App store only allows static frameworks to be used in apps. So I've been converting these frameworks to static. I've completed statically linking OpenSSL using libcrypto.a, and libssl.a files. Currently, trying to figure out how to statically link the other two. Will post answer once it is figured out.

Comment: @AaronMednick did you find solution? how you use .a file as static?